# Phase Sequencer

Tags: power, pic, adc, generator, three-phase

I have 3 phase voltages entering into my PIC ADC (3 different channels )  through a voltage down scaling circuit and I have successfully calculated their rms values inside my controller.Know I want to implement a phase sequencer which would indicated whether the  connected phase wires are in sequence or not and since these phase wires are coming from an AC generator the sequencer will also highlight the direction of motor running .

How can I implement that ? Through Phase calculations  ?

Comment: Look at the times between peaks or zero-crossings.

Comment: I would probably go for measuring peak times rather than ZCD because it will require additional circuitry

Comment: ZCD is more accurate right ?

Comment: By and large, yes. Also, if you don't have well-defined peaks guaranteed, ZCD may be the only way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Ah the old phase sequence detector: -

[image]

Explained [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-10/phase-rotation/).

You can use opto's instead of lamps and get the opto output into a micro GPIO. I built one of these (using neon lamps) back in the 80s. It looks too simple to be effective but it does work!

I've just found this gem: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [seekic.com](http://www.seekic.com/uploadfile/ic-circuit/s2011821214558636.gif))</sub>

There is a brief detail [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191121220807/http://www.seekic.com:80/circuit_diagram/Measuring_and_Test_Circuit/Three_phase_AC_phase_sequence_detector_circuit_diagram.html) about it. Try googling "phase sequence detector".

Here's another neat idea: -

[image]

Forget about all the SSRs and SCR and concentrate on the R and C circuit connected to A and B phases. The blurb on [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170111022352/http://www.tradeofic.com:80/Circuit/4895-PHASE_SEQUENCE_DETECTOR.html) page says

> If phase A lags phase B the input currents will cancel, causing the
>   SCR and the inhibit SSR to remain off until the sequence is reversed.

The R and C circuit basically produces a voltage if the phasing is correct. You could use a comparator on the output (that would feed the SCR) and that would then input to a GPIO pin or do a little IIR filtering in code and achieve the same thing.

Comment: Neat! But given that he already has all 3 phases on ADC channels, detecting positive-going zero crossings in software is probably simpler...

Comment: @BrianDrummond yeah I got carried away with reminiscing but, on the other hand, with a little bit of copy and paste, the 2nd circuit is easily implementable in code - just a bunch of AND gates really. Even the first circuit is doable in code, just a touch of high-pass and low-pass filtering and it's all there. On the other hand, zero crossings need care and attention to not get false ones.

Comment: eh, you're not wrong. Delay one channel via a ring buffer (1/3 the length of the expected period) and compare it with the other two channels...